# Is GWT2.10.0 Java11+ Eclipse compatible?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, java-platform-module-system

I have a large program using GWT Java8 in my Eclipse development environment. I am struggeling hard to understand modules - jigsaw - etc. By reading through all the threads I get bits an pieces that lead me to the conclusion, that this is not sensible to persue.

1. Eclipse does not continue on the GWT3.0 plugin
2. Some statments say -  yes you can use JDK 11+ but you need to generate java 1.8 code
3. From 1 Error with document xml parser I now got tons of errors for naming conventions of module-info.jar ...

Does anyone have overcome these problems and is this combination of tools compatible for coding and debugging?
Which toolchain is properly supporting such a project?

Answer (score 3):

Using a multi module Maven project based on https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes or https://github.com/NaluKit/gwt-maven-springboot-archetype does not require a special IDE. This works well with Eclipse, IntelliJ or any IDE that supports Maven. Even a special GWT plugin is not necessary. I am running my GWT projects using Java 11 without problems.

To your questions:

> Eclipse does not continue on the GWT3.0 plugin

Correct. But people are working on fixing that problem. For more informations, see: https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/issues/406

> Some statments say - yes you can use JDK 11+ but you need to generate
> java 1.8 code

Check [this](https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-ui/issues/634#issuecomment-1164994537) for more informations.